# how to configure a application to run two different ports on JBOSS

Tags: jboss-eap-7

Can somebody help me to configure my application on JBOSS EAP 7 to run on two different ports, currently i have configured on 14441, i have passed the port number in java arguments, and trying to configure, EWS server on top of it

Comment: Do you want server to open two http port ?

Comment: @Abhijit yeah can you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

To configure multiple ports you need to define socket binding and connectors.

1.Add connectors in web subsystem:

```
<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" />
<connector name="http2" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http2" />
```

2. Add socket-binding

   ```
   <socket-binding name="http2" port="8543"/>
   ```

Port 8080 is already define so no need to define it again. Wiht this configuration you should be able see port 8080 and 8543